# How to Link TFDConnection with a TFDManager

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have a Delphi 10 application that has a number of forms in it. Each Form uses a TFDConnection that is created on login with the name "Connection1". Currently the TFDManager is defined in one form and the TFDConnection is defined in another form. Question is how do I link these two together so that TFDConnection inherits some of the setting from TFDManager. Are all TFDConnections in the application automatically linked to TFDManager or is there a setting in TFDConnection that needs to be enabled to link it to TFDManager?

Comment: This is actually many questions in one. This is not allowed by StackIverflow. Please edit your "question" to have a single question and then create as much other questions as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can link two components at design time (Object inspector) from different forms only after you added the other form in the uses clause. Once you do that, in the object inspector the drop down list for a property shows the values from the other form as well.

You can also link them at run time: Assign the property of one to the value of the other.

FDQuery1.Connection := Form1.FDConnection1;

Note that this makes the two forms dependent and you could be in trouble if you don't correctly manage the life time of both forms.

Don't forget to read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDManager)!

Comment: I am new to Dellphi programming, can you please share information on how we can link TFDManager and TFDConnetion at runtime

Comment: One thing I don't like about this answer is that it is incorrect: you *can* in fact link components from different forms using the **Object Inspector** at design time.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I don't know how to do that. Why don't your enter you answer with explanation?

Comment: No, I don't know much about these FireDAC components. But try this: Create a new VCL app, drop a `TPopupMenu` named `PopupMenu1` on the main form (`var Form1: TForm1` in `Unit1`). Create a new form (`var Form2: TForm2` in `Unit2`). Use **File** / **Use unit** (Alt+F11) to add `Unit1` to the implementation section's `uses` clause in `Unit2`. Now you may use the **Object Inspector** to select `Form1.PopupMenu1` as the popup menu of `TForm2`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You are right. I never noticed that since I [almost] never makes a form dependent of another one, considering this as bad practice. But it is valid. I edited my answer to reflect that possibility. Thanks.

Comment: The right place for a centralized connection is the DataModule, which can be accessed by all forms.

Comment: "I never noticed that ..."  Well, what @AndreasRejbrand says has always been true of TDataModules ever since they were introduced, whenever that was (D2/D3?), and you were expected to reference data components on a datamodule from the forms of a project, so I hardly think it can validly be considered "bad practice".

Comment: @MartynA Everyone has his own coding habits and standards. I use DataModule to expose an API for data persistence layer. You have an example there: https://github.com/fpiette/OvbImgOrganizer/blob/main/Source/OvbImgOrganizer.DataModule.pas

Comment: @fpiette:  Sure, I was just making the point that datamodules were introduced specifically as a non-visual container for (non-GUI) data components that could then be referenced by as many forms as required them and to avoid the (imo certainly bad) practice of having one form needing to access another form's data-access components.